# Can we use multiple ou's (organizational unit) in Apache LDAP along with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ldap, organizational-unit

I am new to Apache LDAP with Postgresql. Here I am using postgresql v11 and
apache LDAP v2.0. 
I would like to know does it support multiple organizational unit (OU) configuration in postgresql? If it supports please suggest, How can we configure it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends—how are your groups and users arranged within Postgres itself?

Comment: They are separate users, they don't belong to any group in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind that you need to make a 1-to-1 mapping of roles in Postgres to any external (LDAP-based users), you can do the following:

In `psql`:

```
postgres=# create role ou1;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create role ou2;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create role user1 in role ou1;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create role user2 in role ou2;
CREATE ROLE
```

(Remember, roles are both groups and users -- just one term for both types)

In `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host   all         +ou1      0.0.0.0/0  ldap ldapserver=ldap-service ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=ou1, dc=example, dc=org" ldapport=389
host   all         +ou2      0.0.0.0/0  ldap ldapserver=ldap-service ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=ou2, dc=example, dc=org" ldapport=389
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: host   all         +ou1      0.0.0.0/0  ldap ldapserver=ldap-service ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=ou1, dc=example, dc=org" ldapport=389   just correction.